# better approach to group and sort a single list in kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I have a list which consists of custom objects. I want to to first group the list based on alphabetic order and then sort those groups based on enum values. Let me show you through code:

My list:

```
val list = listOf(Item("America",Severity.CRITICAL), Item("India", Severity.LOW),Item("Australia", Severity.SEVERE),Item("Indonesia", Severity.CRITICAL), Item("Japan", Severity.SEVERE), Item("Jordan", Severity.CRITICAL))
```

My `Severity` enum class:

```
enum class Severity{
 CRITICAL, SEVERE, MODERATE, LOW
}
```

My expected output:

```
val sortedList = listOf(Item("America",Severity.CRITICAL),Item("Australia", Severity.SEVERE),Item("Indonesia", Severity.CRITICAL),Item("India", Severity.LOW), Item("Jordan", Severity.CRITICAL),Item("Japan", Severity.SEVERE))
```

As you can see the list has all the items in alphabetical order and ordered as per the Severity enum class.

**My idea:**

I am planning to create lists inside a list. Those child lists will hold group of all the items in alphabetical order and later I will sort the items of the sub lists based on `Severity` enum values.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you sort by the *first letter*, then by severity?

Comment: Yeah! but maintaining the alphabetical order @Amit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have

`data class Item(val country: String, val severity: Severity)`

and

```
enum class Severity(val value: Int) {
    CRITICAL(0), SEVERE(1), MODERATE(2), LOW(3)
}
```

then

```
val actual = list.sortedWith(
    compareBy(
        { it.country.first() },
        { it.severity.value }
    )
)
```

Comment: Awesome! I could never image that solution.

Comment: can you give a bit of explanation of how this `compareBy` works

Comment: How can I handle cases like if `Item("", Severity.CRITICAL)` has not location. I wanna put them at last.

Comment: What does it mean that an item has no country, but do have a severity? Maybe you have a design issue?

Comment: To be frank there are many more properties in the Item class. But to keep things simple I didnt write them all. So some of the details might come empty and I want to put them at end.

Comment: Oh, I see! Maybe I can have a look at it later, I'm quite busy now. But I wonder if it's better to let country be nullable, then to make it an empty string.